# Sorting struct based on one of each property in C++

Tags: c++

I am a Java and C# programmer. Recently, I am working on C++ project. I am having a problem of how to write the sample code following in C++. The sample code following is to sort a property of a struct:

```
public struct Person
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
}
```

Add some Persons to a list and sort by the age:

```
static void main()
{
   List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

   Person person = new Person();
   person.age = 10;
   person.name = "Jane";

   persons.Add(person);

   person = new Person();
   person.age = 13;
   person.name = "Jack";

   persons.Add(person);

   person = new Person();
   person.age = 12;
   person.name = "Anna";

   persons.Add(person);

   // sort age
   persons.Sort(delegate(Person p1, Person p2) 
   { return p1.age.CompareTo(p2.age); });

   persons.ForEach(delegate(Person p) 
   { Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", p.age, p.name)); });
}
```

How can I write an equivalent sample code in C++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the `Person` type :

```
struct Person
{
    Person(int age_, const std::string &name_)
        : age(age_), name(name_)
    {}

    int age;
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    std::list<Person> persons;
    persons.push_back(Person(10, "Jane"));
    persons.push_back(Person(13, "Jack"));
    persons.push_back(Person(12, "Anna"));
}
```

**Solution 1**

```
bool compareAge(const Person &lhs, const Person &rhs)
{
    return lhs.age < rhs.age;
}

int main()
{
    /* persons list initialization */
    persons.sort(&compareAge);
}
```

**Solution 2 (using [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bind/bind.html))**

```
int main()
{
    /* persons list initialization */
    persons.sort(boost::bind(&Person::age, _1) < boost::bind(&Person::age, _2));
}
```

There also is a solution using [C++0x lambdas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Lambda_functions_and_expressions).

Comment: Hi icecime, thanks a lot for your solutions. I have checked both the solutions but the solution 2 is able to compile but the solution 1 is not. I still prefer the first solution however. The error of the first solution is: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function. Say '&XXX: compareAge'.

Comment: @JoesyXHN: this is because you added `compareAge` *in* the `Person` class, while I defined it as a free function (*outside* the class).

Comment: yes, the solution 2 works perfectly. However, I would like to know a normal comparison method of the solution 1. It does not work for me. If I declare outside, I have to declare the struct as public. But it is private in our case. Furthermore, I tried to make it public but then I got this problem: Invalid use of incomplete type 'const struct xxx:yyy:Person'. I already declared it as a free method. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Another option you have (instead of using list and reordering it by some criteria) could be using `std::map` (or `std::multimap`).

When putting them in `map` they are ordered by the `key`. `std::map` requires unique key, while `std::multimap` may many elements with same key.

```
// multimap< key, value >
std::multimap< int, Person* > IntOrderedMap;

IntOrderedMap ageOrder;

Person* p = new Person( "Jack", 13 );
ageOrder.insert( std::make_pair( p->age, p ) ); // use age as the map key

p = new Person( "Mike", 12 );
ageOrder.insert( std::make_pair( p->age, p ) );

p = new Person( "Paul", 13 );
ageOrder.insert( std::make_pair( p->age, p ) );
```

Then you can traverse it, the elements are ordered by the key (age)

```
for( IntOrderedMap::const_iterator it = ageOrder.begin(); it != ageOrder.end(); ++it )
{
    std::cout << it->second->Name << " is " << it->first << " years old" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Mike is 12 years old
Jack is 13 years old
Paul is 13 years old
```

This allows you at the same time to have another container where the persons are ordered by name.

```
std::multimap nameOrder;
for( IntOrderedMap::const_iterator it = ageOrder.begin(); it != ageOrder.end(); ++it )
{
    Person* p = it->second;
    nameOrder.insert( std::make_pair( p->name, p );
}
```

Comment: this solution is good only if you are sure that you need to sort them only by age

Comment: @wiso I just added example showing that using map gives other options

Comment: This is also a good solution as well. But I prefer to use either the normal comparison method or using the Boost! Thanks!